# Ruby on Rails changes in before_validation on association id not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I'm trying to make sure the order of player ids gets saved out in a consistent manner so we can have composite index on them. The player ids are switched by the end of the before_validation callback and in the validation handler, but are back to their old values in before_save and are saved to the database with the pre-switched values. How do I make sure the proper ordering makes it to the database?

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :player_0, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "player_0_id", :inverse_of => :games
  belongs_to :player_1, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "player_1_id", :inverse_of => :games
  before_validation :ensure_player_order

private

def ensure_player_order
    if self.player_0_id.nil?
      self.player_1_id = self.player_0_id
      self.player_1_id = nil
    elsif !self.player_1_id.nil?
      ids = [self.player_0_id,self.player_1_id]
      low_id = ids.min
      high_id = ids.max

      self.player_0_id = User.find(low_id)
      self.player_1_id = User.find(high_id)
    end
 end
end
```

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the player_0 and player_1 use associations you have to update the association, not the foreign id paired with the association (I think this has to do with ActiveModel::Dirty pulling some shenanigans but I'm not sure). So change ensure_player_order to.

```
def ensure_player_order
    if self.player_0.nil?
      self.player_1 = self.player_0
      self.player_1 = nil
    elsif !self.player_1.nil?
      low = self.player_0.id < self.player_1.id  ? self.player_0 : self.player_1
      high = self.player_0.id < self.player_1.id  ? self.player_1 : self.player_0

      self.player_0 = low
      self.player_1 = high
    end
    true
  end
```